# iOS Subclassing SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, skspritenode, skshapenode

How does one go about subclassing an SKShapeNode that has no instance method initializers? The only way I could think of was this:

```
+ (id)withColor:(UIColor *)aColor radius:(CGFloat)aRadius {
    return [[self alloc] initWithColor:aColor radius: aRadius];
}

- (id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)aColor radius:(CGFloat)aRadius {
    self = (CAButtonNode *)[SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:aRadius];
    self.fillColor = aColor;
    self.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return self;
}
```

In which case `self` is an instance of `SKShapeNode` rather than `CAButtonNode`.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to subclass it though? Can you just configure it or add an extension to SKShapeNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class extension to SKShapeNode

```
extension SKShapeNode
{
    class func nodeWithColor( color:UIColor, radius:Float ) -> Self
    {
        let node = SKShapeNode()
        node.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(...)
        node.fillColor = ...
        node.strokeColor = ...

        return node
    }
}
```

Use like this:

`let newNode = SKShapeNode.nodeWithColor( theColor, radius: theRadius )`

Or, in Obj-C:

```
@implementation SKShapeNode (NodeWithColorAndRadius)

+(instancetype)nodeWithColor:(UIColor*)color radius:(CGFloat)r
{
    SKShapeNode * result = [ self new ] ;
    result.path = ...;
    result.fillColor = ...;
    result.strokeColor = ...;
}

@end
```

Call like this:

`[ SKShapeNode nodeWithColor:theColor radius:theRadius ]`

Comment: Oh nice! I never thought of using an extension.  In cases like this is it better practice to use an extension or subclass? Or is it really personal preference?

Comment: Extensions paint you into less corners. I always extend or compose (has-a relationships) in preference to subclassing (is-a relationships). Of course, building extensions is a type if is-a relationship, but it's way more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty inconvenient if you ask me and I'm not sure if this is the correct solution, but it does work. I'm leaving this here for anyone who might run into a similar problem.

What you have to do is call `[super init]` like you would normally, and then manually set the node's path. The following basically mimics the `SKShapeNode` class method `shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:`

```
- (id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)aColor radius:(CGFloat)aRadius {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(-aRadius, -aRadius, aRadius * 2, aRadius * 2), NULL);
        self.fillColor = aColor;
        self.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

If anyone knows, I'm curious as to why they didn't include the instance method initializers like they do in most other classes.

Cheers!